# How to insert an xml file in a single cell of sql table

Tags: php, xml, mysqlimport

I have a .xml file in my computer and i want it to be inserted in a single column and single cell of a sql table corresponding to serial no.s so that i can create a link on web page that would be directly downloadable from web page when clicking on it .I've searched everywhere but what i am getting is insert xml data in a table or how to upload a file on web page .

But i want them to be already uploaded on web page and when clicking on a link it will be directly downloaded on user,s local machine. So for this , I've to put those files in a column corresponding to their serial no.s then using php i can make those files downloadable to user machine .How is this possible have any idea...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this link "http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx"

This is a tutorial where you can insert xml file into database and also can create its downloadable link .This may help you.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for .Thank you for sending me this link its a great tutorial really helpful thnx alot.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In such case I would encode whole content of XML file using base64 before inserting into single database cell. And when using direct link use a php script which selects that cell, decodes data and simply outputs as xml.

If xml files are quite big, it is recommended to use gzip for compressing data before encoding with base64.

Did I understood your question correctly?

Comment: Yeah, exactly you get it right . So the problem is how to insert those xml files in a single cell so that php can read it directly when clicking on a link . how is it possible..??